# Handling the logout of the react app with AuthContext

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, logout

I have been following this tutorial
https://dev.to/embeddednature/create-an-authorization-flow-with-react-navigation-5-x-2pkh

Now the navigation works fine, but I don't get the logout button to work. I just don't know, whats the proper position to add my code and how to connect that code to a button.

When I press the logout Button, nothing happens. And I am not sure how the line `const {signOut} = useContext(AuthContext);`works. Am I supposed to create a function `signOut`in the AuthContext?

here's the part of my code

```
const createDrawer = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const {signOut} = useContext(AuthContext);

    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          },
        }}>

            <Drawer.Screen
                name="Overview"
                component={HomeScreen}
                options={{
                  headerRight:  () => (
                    <Button
                      onPress={() => signOut}
                      title="Logout"
                      color="#fff"
                    />
                  ),
                }}

            />
            <Drawer.Screen
               name="GameplayScreen"
               component={GameplayScreen}
               options={{
                 title: 'Playing',
               }}
                />


        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

finally I found the answer myself:

within the sample's AuthContext, a signOut function needs to be specified. And there we have to set the state isSigned to false.
The sample works like expected, and it shows the login screen.

```
export const AuthContext = createContext({
  signOut: () => {  
    AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', null);
    state.isSignedIn = false;
  }
});
```